# .htaccess Apache URL Rewrite for Wordpress - permanently pointing one domain to another

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to point www.olddomain.com/whatever to www.newdomain.com/whatever (as well as without the www.), but the Wordpress permalinks are not staying intact. Please help!!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not staying intact"? What happens?

Comment: it just redirects to the home page /index.php

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler solution. Change the .htaccess to just say:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1
```

Comment: Awesome much simpler solution!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move this block:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

*behind* the redirects. It grabs everything and sends it to index.php.

Comment: now I get a 301 moved permanently error - but the "new" URL is the same as the old.

Comment: Strange. You could try adding "L": `[r=301,nc,l]` but it should work as it is, don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: @Paul where you have the `[r=301,nc]` now... But the `r` should already end processing and start the redirect, so I don't think that's it